# How to validate person_ids in Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my Rails app, I have a `has_many through` relationship between two models and therefore I am creating new objects like this:

```
Project.new(:name => 'Test', :person_ids => [1, 2, 3])
```

What is a good way to validate those `person_ids` in the model?

This is what I have so far:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :people_projects 
  has_many :people, :through => :people_projects 

  validates :person_ids, inclusion => { :in => lambda { |x| x.valid_people } }

  def valid_people
    user.people.map(&:id)   
  end    

end
```

However, this doesn't work because the `person_ids` get posted in an array.

Can anybody help?

Comment: can you show your relationships and tell exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: @rb512: I added some more information above.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated

Comment: @depa: No, it's not actually. But thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom validation method like

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :valid_people

  def valid_people
    people = user.people.pluck(:id)
    if person_ids.blank? || (person_ids - people).any?
      errors.add(:person_ids, "Please add real people")
    end
  end    

end
```

Comment: Instead of `!(...).blank?`, you could also use `(...).any?` which removes the double negation.

Comment: @Tintin81.. yes, that was a typo :)